# WorkThanks.FeedItem getting null

Tags: force.com, work.com

Below is my code snippet to give thanks to user, I noticed that related child record of FeedItem is getting null (WorkThanks). However it is working when I gives thank from chatter of classic salesforce.

```
String loggedUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
System.debug(loggedUser);
WorkThanks thanks = new WorkThanks();               
thanks.GiverId = loggedUser;
thanks.Message = 'test_message_002';
insert thanks;
System.debug(thanks);

//create feed
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = loggedUser;//'0051a000001Z9HQAA0';
post.Body = 'test_message_002';
post.CreatedById = loggedUser;
post.Type = 'RypplePost';
post.RelatedRecordId = thanks.Id;

insert post;
System.debug(post);
System.debug(post.FeedItemThanks);//This should return thanks RelatedRecord

//create badge
WorkBadge badge = new WorkBadge();
....
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your `System.debug(post.FeedItemThanks)` is returning null because you didn't request this field from the database.

In fact, you just inserted a record by using the RelatedRecordId field to link to your WorkThanks. The FeedItemThanks field is not set on your insert.

If you want to log it, you will have to request this field from the database like this:

```
//create feed
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = loggedUser;//'0051a000001Z9HQAA0';
post.Body = 'test_message_002';
post.CreatedById = loggedUser;
post.Type = 'RypplePost';
post.RelatedRecordId = thanks.Id;

insert post;

post = [SELECT FeedItemThanks FROM FeedItem WHERE Id = :post.Id];

System.debug(post.FeedItemThanks);
```

Comment: It is not inserted into database as well. here is my query,  
    post = [Select f.RelatedRecordId, f.Id, f.Body, (Select Id, Message From FeedItemThanks) From FeedItem f
    WHERE f.Id = :post.Id];
    System.debug(post);
    System.debug(post.FeedItemThanks);